# Excluding classes with dynamic classloading

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-management, dynamic-class-loaders

I'm trying to build a medium sized Java project to keep it as modular and scalable possible. To do that, the main architecture will only be responsible of loading some classes provided in jars (the modules) possibly at runtime. This solution will obviously require dynamic class loading, but it will reduce the coupling of components to minimum.

Now, comes the problem though. Each module may have dependency on some libraries (let's say for example Hibernate, Spring...). To avoid dependency hell, I'm putting all the libraries in one project along with the architecture interface and including this project as a dependency of all the modules. Ideally, I'd like to dinamically exclude this dependency-project from classloading to avoid problems at runtime.

Here's my questions:

- First of all, is this a good idea? Would be there a better approach to this problem that I'm missing?
- Is this something I should concern about? Or the fact that I'm including the same classes more than once won't be a problem?
- If it is a problem, what would be the best way to exclude that classes from loading? I was thinking of filtering them by package but I'm not sure.

I'm still not so sure if going with this kind of architecture or instead using Maven to build statically the full project excluding the dependency project on each module.

Any suggestion on how to proceed is really appreciated.

At the moment I'm using Maven to build and Spring as a framework, but I don't mind adding other technologies.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess the standard approach is to let maven/gradle/.. handle dependencies pre-buildtime, as those tools have ways to exclude dependencies and resolve depenceny-hell - given that you declare for each component what it needs rather than having a big blob of potential dependencies. Edit: maybe you could have a look at "parent projects" like https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml

Comment: This is indeed the standard, but you can't achieve true modularity this way: assuming my application is running on a server, in order to plug in a module I'd have to stop the server, recompile everything and then deploy again. This will make the architecture coupled with the modules.

Comment: I don't really see where you see problematic coupling with the standard approach, while requiring a special runtime environment is less of a concern. Also what if you want to update that? Or one of the dependencies in the core architecture thing. You'll have to be able to restart your application with new code anyways.

Comment: I don’t get it. You want to *exclude* the classes that all others *depend on* from class loading? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: @Holger that won't work for sure. I wanted to use a different classloader for each module of my application. If all my modules uses the same package of dependencies, this would have meant that each classloader would have loaded all the dependencies. I wanted to avoid that, although, after zapl answer I'm checking if I could take a more static approach as he suggested.

Comment: You know that class loader have a parent loader? The standard behavior is that a class loader checks the parent loader *first*, before looking into its own resources. If the prerequisites are available through a parent loader, no child loader will clone them. This setup is even *required*, if you expect each module to agree on the identity of the common interfaces.

Comment: So, if I've understood correctly, including the same dependencies more than once won't be a problem as long as the architecture's classloader has the same dependencies. These will be always the same picked. Is this correct?

Comment: I'd like to accept an actual answer if any of you wrote one. Thank you.